Handling Google Analytics Data Exceeding 10,000 Rows per Day: Pagination and Dimension Filtering Challenges with google.analytics.data_v1beta API"
I'm using the google.analytics.data_v1beta API to access Google Analytics data. I'm facing an issue with the 10,000-row limit per query, whereas I need to handle more than 10,000 rows per day.
Currently, I'm struggling to implement pagination and utilize dimension_filter with this API. Does anyone know an effective approach to work around these limits and manage queries with a large volume of data?
I've tried implementing pagination by row limit and making multiple queries, but this is not allowed by the google.analytics.data_v1beta API.
I've also attempted pagination by date and time, but unfortunately, this is not supported by the API.
Furthermore, I've tried applying filters using dimensions, but this functionality is also not available.

Can you link to where you've seen these limits? I'm trying to google but don't see anything like 10k rows/day. That's just nothing. We export them by millions/day.

Have a look at the pagination section in this document.
request = RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[Dimension(name="foo")],
    metrics=[Metric(name="bar")],
    date_ranges=[
        DateRange(
            start_date="today",
            end_date="today",
        ),
    ],
    limit=100000,
    offset=0,
)

Simply create a loop that increments the offset value by the amount of the limit value and you should be good.

Thanks! Not knowing about the [Limit] property, this was exactly what I needed. Apparently in GA4 the default/unspecified is 10,000, and the max in a single API call is up to 250,000.
https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/analytics-data/latest/V1beta.RunReportRequest
